# Fix footer in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've managed to make the image stick to the footer but failed to make the footer stick to the bottom when entering responsive mode. I'm a newbie to bootstrap so help is appreciated.

HTML: The footer is after the table.

```
<div class="instructables-container" id="instructables" style="position: relative; margin-left: 0px;height: 10px; ">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading" style="color: #2E2E2E; text-align: center;">INSTRUCTABLES</h2>
                <hr class="primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-box">
                        <p style="font-size: 60px;">x</p>
                        <p>Instructables</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-box">
                       <p style="font-size: 60px;">x</p>
                        <p>xx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-box">
                        <p style="font-size: 60px;">x</p>
                        <p>xx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-box">
                        <p style="font-size: 60px;">x</p>
                        <p>xx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 </div> 

  <div class="footer" style="height:30%; background-color: white;">
        <div class="robot" style="position: absolute; margin:auto; left:0; right:0; bottom: 20px;">
            <a href="http://instructables.com/member/neroliko"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/q7GBNF1.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="words" style="position: absolute; width:100%;background-color:#E6E6E6; bottom:0px;">
             <p style=" font-size: 13px; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Georgia, serif;">Contact: nerolikkh@gmail.com </p>
        </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.instructables-container {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

.table{
    margin-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 11%;
    border: 0px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: You want the footer stick bottom only when in mobile resolution or when? And an advice, don't use inline css unless the code is for email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.instructables-container {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}

.table{
    margin-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 11%;
    border: 0px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    height:400px;
}
.test div{
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="instructables-container" id="instructables" style="position: relative; margin-left: 0px;height: 10px; ">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading" style="color: #2E2E2E; text-align: center;">INSTRUCTABLES</h2>
                <hr class="primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row test">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-box">
                        <p style="font-size: 60px;">x</p>
                        <p>Instructables</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-box">
                       <p style="font-size: 60px;">x</p>
                        <p>xx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-box">
                        <p style="font-size: 60px;">x</p>
                        <p>xx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-6 text-center">
                    <div class="service-box">
                        <p style="font-size: 60px;">x</p>
                        <p>xx</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 </div> 

  <div class="footer" style="height:30%; background-color: white;">
        <div class="robot" style="position: absolute; margin:auto; left:0; right:0; bottom: 20px;">
            <a href="http://instructables.com/member/neroliko"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/q7GBNF1.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="words" style="position: absolute; width:100%;background-color:#E6E6E6; bottom:0px;">
             <p style=" font-size: 13px; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Georgia, serif;">Contact: nerolikkh@gmail.com </p>
        </div>
  </div>
```

You should add the correct classes for mobile screen so you should define the width that you want for each div in mobile screen. You can use bootstrap class for that `.col-xs-6` so one of these divs will be half of screen. Here is your html code and also a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z56f24f/1/)

And it's not good to use inline style you should use it as internal or external!

Comment: Yeah I know it's not good to use inline style but it takes so long before the change in css style sheet appears on my browser. Thank you anyways!